# Solr with calculated Price field

Tags: solr, solr4, solrnet

I am having a Solr used for my eCommerce search. With single currency it works great. However, I am not sure how to have another currency to Solr and do a facet range queries on the same. This another currency is actually calculated using a live exchange rate. I am not sure how to implement the same into Solr.

I have facets on Price as well as Price Range filter on search page. Moreover, Price is used for sorting.

So if its just about displaying Price in another currency I can handle easily on View side, but how to have all these faceting  & sorting from Solr to be applied on this Calculated Price in another currency.

One idea is to have calculated filed using mathematical function, but I'm not sure if that supports faceting, sorting, etc. Moreover, currency is dynamic and changes frequently so we also need to update math function frequently.

Any idea on the same will be appreciable.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: There's [a patch available for an older version of Solr](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-3218) (.. and if you're on solr4, that might still apply), so test it out and if it works, see if you can contribute time to get proper currency faceting to Solr. :-)

Comment: Sorry Didn't get it. Patch for what?

Comment: For using a Currency field for faceting. A currency field allows you to index a price in one currency and do real time conversion to other currencies in Solr.

Comment: How to do that in Solr? I'm asking for currency conversion in Solr

Comment: Use [a currency field](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/working-with-currencies-and-exchange-rates.html). At least try a rudimentary web search if someone points you in a certain direction. But as I said in my first comment, to be able to do faceting, you'll have to apply the linked patch and try it out.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in right direction. I'll try it out.

Answer (score 0):

If currency exchange raten it's dynamic, you could use a function, but the easiest solución it's to store just the principal currency in solr and convert it in your app before querying solr and again whith the results from solr.

Comment: Does using a function I can have facet range query on it? Sort, etc

Comment: Maybe with the json request api you can get something, but I really think that the easiest way it's to work always with the original price and make the conversion in the client, Actually it's what solr currency system does, as it's only stores the original price. Specially if you are using solrnet, which doesn't have all the features of the java client.

Comment: Hi, I think you're right. I'll try working with Json API to work with same.